# How can I encrypt existing data in ALL Azure storage accounts across multiple subscriptions

Tags: azure, encryption, storage

There is old, unencrypted data that has to be encrypted. I enabled encryption for future data but want to make sure all data across storage accounts is encrypted at rest.

I know that I can use [AZCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy) to move data, but is there a way to keep the current storage accounts but encrypt the data inside?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no other way to encrypt existing data.

SSE only encrypts newly created data after the encryption is enabled. If for example you create a new Resource Manager storage account but don't turn on encryption, and then you upload blobs or archived VHDs to that storage account and then turn on SSE, those blobs will not be encrypted unless they are rewritten or copied.

Comment: Can I copy from one storage account to itself and have it encrypted along the way?

Answer (score 0):

Only option to encrypt the data within the same Storage Account is to copy the data to another container.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-service-encryption

Comment: The problem I have is that the storage account names are procedurally generated from an ARM template, so I'd need to make a new storage account, transfer the data, and then transfer the data back to the first storage account

Comment: you can make a new container in your storage account and copy the data to the new container and the data will be encrypted. Depending on how you access the data you either copy the data back to the original container or not but you still have the same storage account.

Comment: Is there a way to programmatically create a new container, copy the data, and copy it back? There's a huge number of storage accounts that have to be encrypted and I can't realistically do it manually

Comment: I don't have a finished script but you use New-AzureStorageContainer to create new containers https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/new-azurestoragecontainer?view=azurermps-5.0.0 and Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy to copy all blobs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/start-azurestorageblobcopy?view=azurermps-5.0.0

Comment: Ok, I'll try to find some time to write a script to do that and edit the original post with a link to it

Comment: My script works on smaller files but there are some containers that are so big that Azure can't enumerate all the blobs in them. When I run the script on them, it says "Active: 1" for a while but closes after a couple hours. Is it possible that the container is so big that the Copy operation cannot be performed on it?

Comment: Everything is possible, think it all depends on how you copy the files, Powershell, .NET, AzCopy etc. For an example AzCopy will resume any aborted/interrupted jobs.

Comment: I'm doing all this through powershell